# wcf service hosting on windows service installation error

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-services

when i install wcf service hosting on windows service using InstallUtil i get the following Error Message.

An exception occurred during the Rollback phase of the System.ServiceProcess.Ser
viceProcessInstaller installer.
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an obj
ect.
An exception occurred during the Rollback phase of the installation. This except
ion will be ignored and the rollback will continue. However, the machine might n
ot fully revert to its initial state after the rollback is complete.

The Rollback phase completed successfully.

The transacted install has completed.
The installation failed, and the rollback has been performed.

Can You please tell me how to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do it as an Admin. I mean to say run a command prompt as an Admin and try. I had the same error and solved using this technique.

Answer (score 0):

There should be more information in the assemblyname.InstallLog file. Check for errors there first.

Comment: this is what i get in my log : Installing assembly 

Rolling back assembly 'C:\Users\TC\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\ABCService\ABCService\bin\Debug\ABCService.exe'.
Affected parameters are:
   logtoconsole = 
   logfile = <log file path>
   assemblypath = <assembly path>
An exception occurred during the Rollback phase of the System.ServiceProcess.ServiceProcessInstaller installer.
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
An exception occurred during the Rollback phase of the installation.

Comment: I am guessing that you are running InstallUtil from command line. Add /ShowCallStack to see if you can get more information.

Answer (score 0):

Check the application event log, run this:

```
eventvwr.msc
```

You can see there the details of the *real* exception your'e getting.

If you're `System.ServiceModel` settings is in the configuration file, the error you're getting might be because of an invalid configuration settings.

You can follow [this tutorial in installing a *Managed Windows Service*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733069.aspx) if you're having a hard time in the installation.